# How to encrypt/decrypt URL parameters in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I want to Encrypt/Decrypt the parameter on the URL. Because when the user deliberately changes the id parameter, it still returns the result.

For example: https://script.google.com/xxxxxxxxx/exec?v=edit&ac=A00001 when user change A00003 it still returns the result. This is the problem

Is there any way to encrypt like https://script.google.com/xxxxxxxxx/exec?kabhshcjsgsj123455123 and way backend parse "kabhshcjsgsj123455123"   to   "v=edit&ac=A00001" ???

Comment: Please use proper tags. Read user guideline of [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to use the encrypted query parameters as the query parameter of Web Apps.

  - You want to use the encrypted query parameters like `https://script.google.com/xxxxxxxxx/exec?kabhshcjsgsj123455123`.
  - For example, when the actual query parameter is `v=edit&ac=A00001`, you don't want to make users modify the values.
- Your Web Apps uses `doGet(e)`. You want to retrieve the values from the event object of `e`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers. In this answer, as a simple method, I use the base64 for your situation. The sample script is as follows. In this case, there are 2 scripts for the client side and server side.

#### Sample script: Client side

```
function fordoget() {
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set the URL of Web Apps.
  var value = {v: "edit", ac: "A00001"}; // I used "v=edit&ac=A00001" as an object.
  var encryptedValue = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(value));
  url += "?" + encryptedValue;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(res)
}
```

- Before you use this, please deploy Web Apps.
- This is a sample script of Google Apps Script. So if you want to use other language, please modify this.
- I thought that when `v=edit&ac=A00001` is used as an object of `{v: "edit", ac: "A00001"}`, this is easy to use at the server side.

  - In above sample script, the URL becomes like below.

    - `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?eyJ2IjoiZWRpdCIsImFjIjoiQTAwMDAxIn0=`.

#### Sample script: Server side

```
function doGet(e) {
  var encryptedValue = Object.keys(e.parameter)[0];
  var decryptedValue = JSON.parse(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(encryptedValue)).getDataAsString());

  // decryptedValue.v is "edit"
  // decryptedValue.ac is "A00001"

  // do something.

}
```

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please deploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected. Please be careful this.**
- In this sample, it supposes that `Execute the app as` and `Who has access to the app` are set as `Me` and `Anyone, even anonymous`, respectively.
- In the case of `https://script.google.com/xxxxxxxxx/exec?kabhshcjsgsj123455123`, `kabhshcjsgsj123455123` is the key of query parameter. And the value is `""`. Please be careful this.
- I think that the limitation of the size of value. Please be careful this.
- In above sample script, the parameters can be retrieved by as follows.

  - `decryptedValue.v` is `edit`.
  - `decryptedValue.ac` is `A00001`.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata_1)
- [base64Decode(encoded)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, your knowledge will be very helpful to me. Best regards !

Comment: @Naoa Lee Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.